# Send selected data back to original window

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, modal-dialog, custom-data-attribute

I have a file called bpSearch.  Inside bpSearch, I have a MODAL window, called addNewModal.  Within addNewModal, I have 2 INPUT fields called partnerName and partnerCode. I have a button that once clicked, opens into another MODAL window, called searchPartnerModal.

Here is the a portion of the FORM inside addNewModal:

```
 <form action="bpSearch.php" method="get">
   <input type="text" readonly id="partnerName" name="partnerName" />
   <input type="text" readonly id="partnerCode" name="partnerCode" />
   <a href="#searchPartnerModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">Go</a>
 </form>
```

When the user clicks GO, it opens searchPartnerModal.

searchPartnerModal is where the user will enter either a code or a name (doesn't have to be both). But upon hitting SEARCH, I use an AJAX call that returns JSON that I parse and eventually return in a UL field called pNames.  We're still inside searchPartnerModal.

Here is the FORM inside searchPartnerModal:

```
 <form action="bpSearch.php" method="get">
   <input type="text" id="pNameSearch" name="pNameSearch" />
   <input type="text" id="pCodeSearch" name="pCodeSearch" />
   <input type="button" class="btn" id="pSearch" name="pSearch" value="search" />
 </form>
```

When the user enters a name, I use jquery to send it over to a PHP script that will then return the data in a UL tag.

Here is the jquery that will search if the user enters a name:

```
 $('#pSearch').on('click', function()
 {
   var partnername = $('#pNameSearch').val();
   if($.trim(partnername) != '')
   {
     $.post('api/pNameSearch.php', {partnername: partnername}, function(data)
     {
       var obj = JSON.parse(data);
       $('#pNames').empty();    
       var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item)
       {
         return '<li><a id="getPInfo" href="javascript:;"
         onclick="getPInfo()" data-selname="'+item.FULL_NAME+'" 
         data-selcode="'+item.PARTNER_CODE+'">'
          + item.FULL_NAME + ' - '
          + item.PARTNER_CODE + '</a></li>';
       }).join('');
       $('#pNames').html(htmlToInsert);
     });
   };
 });
```

With this code, I am able to send the name to search the database table for a valid name.  The data is returned via JSON and is parsed and displayed inside the UL tag (called pNames) as LI tags, each with an A tag with their own data-attributes, called data-selname and data-selcode.

Now what I need to do is once the user clicks on one of the returned data links inside pNames, I need to send it back to the previous modal window, addNewModal.

This is where I'm stuck.

If you look inside the Jquery above, after I parsed the JSON, you will see that I created another Javascript function inside the A tag of each returned piece of data, called getPInfo().

Here is what I got so far for the function getPInfo() :

```
 function getPInfo()
 {
   var selname = ($('#getPInfo').attr('data-selname'));
   var selcode = ($('#getPInfo').attr('data-selcode'));
 }
```

At this point, I can alert both variables (selname and selcode) and get them to display in an alert window.

What I want to do is send both of those variables back to addNewModal in the respective INPUT fields, called partnerName and partnerCode.

So selname will go to partnerName and selcode will go to partnerCode.

I didn't display the PHP script that returned the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the anchor **id=getPInfo** to **class=getPInfo** since you have multiple anchors. Next, handle the click event of the anchor and extract the data attributes and set the corresponding form elements in the addNewModal form. Following should work based on the markup i see so far.

```
$(function(){
   $('body').on('click', 'a.getPInfo', function (e) {
      var $a = $(e.srcElement || e.target);
      $('#partnerName').val($a.attr('data-selname'));
      $('#partnerCode').val($a.attr('data-selcode'));
      $('#searchPartnerModal').modal('hide'); //assuming bootstrap modal
   });
});
```

Comment: In my first modal, addNewModal, I added into the class of the INPUT types where partnerName and partnerCode are located.  Then, using the javascript above, I changed $('#partnerName') to $('.partnerName') and got the results I was looking for.  Thanks to @Athen Holloway